# masonry overlay in angular 7

Tags: angular, masonry

I am using a masonry design in my angular application: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry

My problem is that some items overlap:
[image]

When I change the size of the window manually it looks good:
[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

**module.ts**

```
import { NgxMasonryModule } from 'ngx-masonry';
imports: [ NgxMasonryModule]
```

**component.html**

```
<ngx-masonry class="row small-gutters">
     <div ngxMasonryItem *ngFor="let evento of eventos | async" class="py-0 grid-five col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 my-2">
            <div class="aviso">
                <a [routerLink]="['/evento', evento.id]" class="text-white">
                    <img src="{{ evento.imagen }}" class="rounded" alt="{{ evento.titulo }}" width=100%>
                    <div class="pt-1 pt-md-2 d-flex align-items-start">
                        <div class="fechaThumbnail d-none d-lg-block">
                            <h4 class="dia">{{ evento.fechaInicio.toDate() | date: 'dd' }}</h4>
                            <h6 class="mes">{{ evento.fechaInicio.toDate() | date: 'LLL' | uppercase | slice:0:3 }}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h6 class="font-weight-light mb-0 text-primary">{{ evento.titulo | truncate: 42 }}</h6>
                            <div class="small font-weight-light op-50 mt-1">
                                <span class="d-none d-lg-block">{{ evento.direccion | truncate: 25 }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
 </ngx-masonry>
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid overlapping issues you have to add following code to the ngx-masonry tag
[useImagesLoaded]="true"

Kindly read comments for actual tag

Note : I also faced same issues of overlapping.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: e.g : <ngx-masonry [useImagesLoaded]="true"></ngx-masonry>

Answer (score 1):

please update your code like this

add property [useImagesLoaded]="true" in div tag. next to ngxMasonryItem